# Changing the pattern for CHF currency in Java using icu package?

Tags: java, locale, currency, icu

I wrote a java function that shows the locale pattern for each currency. See the function below. What I am interested to know is that why when the currency is CHF, the 2nd decimal is hardcoded to 5?
Note that I am using icu package and this issue doesn't exist with java.util.Currency package. I am using the default locale of en_US.
Here is the output of the function which is related to USD and CHF currencies:

```
Analyzing currency: [USD] localePattern: [¤#,##0.00;(¤#,##0.00)] Currency symbol [$]
Analyzing currency: [CHF] localePattern: [¤#,##0.05;(¤#,##0.05)] Currency symbol [SwF]
```

Here is the java function I wrote:

```
import com.ibm.icu.text.DecimalFormat; 
import com.ibm.icu.text.NumberFormat;
import com.ibm.icu.util.Currency;

public static void main(String[] args)
  {
    Currency configuredCurrency                       = null; 
    NumberFormat formatter                = NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance();
    DecimalFormat localeCurrencyFormatter = (DecimalFormat)formatter;
    String localePattern                  = "";
    String symbol                         = "";

    String currencies        = "AED,AFN,ALL,AMD,ARS,AUD,BGN,BHD,BND,BOB,BRL,BWP,BYR,CAD,CHF,CLP,CNY,COP,CRC,CZK,DJF,DKK,DOP,DZD,EEK,EGP,ERN,ETB,EUR,GBP,GTQ,HKD,HNL,HRK,HUF,IDR,ILS,INR,IQD,IRR,ISK,JOD,JPY,KES,KPW,KRW,KWD,KZT,LBP,LTL,LVL,LYD,MAD,MKD,MTL,MXN,MYR,NIO,NOK,NZD,OMR,PAB,PEN,PHP,PKR,PLN,PYG,QAR,RON,RUB,SAR,SDD,SEK,SGD,SKK,SOS,SVC,SYP,SwF,THB,TND,TRY,TZS,UAH,USD,UYU,VEB,VND,YER,ZAR,ZWD";
    String[] currenciesArray = currencies.split(",");

    for (int i = 0; i < currenciesArray.length; i++)
    {
      String currency = currenciesArray[i];
      configuredCurrency = Currency.getInstance(currency);
      localeCurrencyFormatter.setCurrency(configuredCurrency);
      localePattern = localeCurrencyFormatter.toPattern();
      symbol = localeCurrencyFormatter.getCurrency().getSymbol();

      System.out.println("Analyzing currency: [" + currency + "] localePattern: [" + localePattern + "] Currency symbol [" + symbol + "]");
    } 
  }
```

Answer (score 3):

The 5 there is the rounding increment (there is no 0.01 of Swiss franc, 0.05 is the least valuable coin ([Swiss franc wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Swiss_franc))).

Also from the icu4j DecimalFormat [javadoc](http://www.jarvana.com/jarvana/view/com/ibm/icu/icu4j/4.0.1/icu4j-4.0.1-javadoc.jar!/com/ibm/icu/text/DecimalFormat.html):

**"In place of '0', the digits '1' through '9' may be used to indicate a rounding increment."**

Comment: What I need to achieve is to be able to avoid this case and read the amounts with 2 decimals.

Answer (score 1):

The '5' tells the ICU package that there are special rules about how to round the number to the nearest 5/100ths when converting to a string form.

"In Switzerland, five centimes are the smallest currency unit for payment transactions. For Swiss company codes and the currency Swiss franc, you therefore enter 5 ."

[SAP help web site](http://help.sap.com/saphelp_40b/helpdata/en/b1/e364b20437d1118b3f0060b03ca329/frameset.htm)

Comment: Even if the smallest coin is 5 rappen and therefore requires cash transactions to be rounded, there seem to be no restriction in Switzerland that other transactions cannot be made with any arbritary amount, e.g. a 1.23 CHF bank transfer.

Answer (score 1):

Thank you all for the help. I was finally able to find an answer. I wrote this piece of code and did the trick:

```
localeCurrencyFormatter.setRoundingIncrement(new BigDecimal("0"));
```